# How do I update database using select form and submit?

Tags: php, database, select, sql-update, form-submit

My db-table `aktivitet` has a column called status. The functionality is when an event is done you´re supposed to switch the status from `Ej Klar(Not Done)` to `Klar(Done)` with the help of a select form and a submit-button. 
I´ve been sitting here for two days in a row, I´ve tried many different approaches but I just cant´get it to work. Please help me figure this out?

Here´s the code

```
<?php
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=orion_db2;host=localhost', 'root', '');                                                            
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING );    

echo "<table class='table' border='2'>";
echo "<th style='background-color:#334d4d;'><h1>Tid</h1></th>";
echo "<th style='background-color:#334d4d;'><h1>Uppgift</h1></th>";
echo "<th style='background-color:#334d4d;'><h1>Status</h1></th>";

foreach($pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM aktivitet;' ) as $row){                                                                          
    $status = $row['status'];
    if($status == 'Ej Klar'){
        $status = 'Ej Klar';
    }
    elseif($status == 'Klar'){
        $status = 'Klar';
    }

    echo "<tr>";                                                                                                                                       
    echo "<td><h2>".$row['tid']."</h2></td>";                                                                                                                
    echo "<td><h2>".$row['uppgift']."</h2></td>";
    echo "<td><h3><form method='POST' action='index.php' name='stat'><select id='status' name='status'  size='1' required><option value='Ej Klar' <?php if($status == 'Ej Klar') echo 'selected'; ?>Ej Klar</option><option value='Klar' <?php if($status == 'Klar') echo 'selected'; ?>Klar</option></optgroup><input type='submit' value='Ändra' /></select></form></h3></td>";
    echo "</tr>";                                                                                                                                      
}      
echo "</table>";
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $status2 = $_POST['status'];
    $sql = "UPDATE members SET status=:status WHERE status=:status";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bindValue(":status", $status2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->execute();
}
?>
```

Comment: What's the behaviour/result when you run this?

Comment: The semi-colon in here `foreach($pdo->query( 'SELECT * FROM aktivitet;' ) as $row)` is stopping its execution right there.

Comment: and this `if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {...}` will never fire up. Here, see for yourself http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php - Plus, `if($status == 'Ej Klar')` that is case-sensitive.

Comment: The table displays as it should and I can flip between status Not Done and Done with the select form but it doesnt store any changes in the DB

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This is how it looks. Got to be someway to uppdate the DB in this way?